# Why does curl work with a specific https site, but wget has problems with certificates?

Tags: certificate-authority, curl, wget

Centos 6. After updating recently ca-certificates I run into some troubles. I have the most recent versions of curl for centos 6:

```
-bash-4.1$ curl -V -v
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

And wget:

```
-bash-4.1$ wget -V -v
GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.

+digest +ipv6 +nls +ntlm +opie +md5/openssl +https -gnutls +openssl 
-iri 

Wgetrc: 
    /etc/wgetrc (system)
Locale: /usr/share/locale 
Compile: gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -O2 -g -pipe -Wall 
    -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector 
    --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing 
Link: gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions 
    -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic 
    -fno-strict-aliasing -Wl,-z,relro -lssl -lcrypto 
    /usr/lib64/libssl.so /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so -ldl -lrt ftp-opie.o 
    openssl.o http-ntlm.o gen-md5.o ../lib/libgnu.a 

Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Currently maintained by Micah Cowan <micah@cowan.name>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
```

Now I have problem with certificates from CA https://www.certum.pl/ . curl works fine:

```
-bash-4.1$ curl -v 'https://certum.pl/'
* About to connect() to certum.pl port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 213.222.201.147... connected
* Connected to certum.pl (213.222.201.147) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=certum.pl,businessCategory=Private Organization,serialNumber=0000421310,incorporationState=pomorskie,incorporationLocality=Gdańsk,incorporationCountry=PL,postalCode=81-321,STREET=Podolska 21,ST=pomorskie,L=Gdynia,OU=Certification Authority Division,O=Asseco Data Systems S.A.,C=PL
*       start date: Aug 16 09:10:07 2017 GMT
*       expire date: Aug 16 09:10:07 2019 GMT
*       common name: certum.pl
*       issuer: CN=Certum Extended Validation CA SHA2,OU=Certum Certification Authority,O=Unizeto Technologies S.A.,C=PL
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: certum.pl
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 07:02:41 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: https://www.certum.pl/pl/
< Content-Length: 209
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.certum.pl/pl/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Closing connection #0
```

But wget returns `ERROR`:

```
-bash-4.1$ wget -d -O-  'https://certum.pl/'
Setting --output-document (outputdocument) to -
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.

--2018-07-17 09:04:42--  https://certum.pl/
Resolving certum.pl... 213.222.201.147
Caching certum.pl => 213.222.201.147
Connecting to certum.pl|213.222.201.147|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000000d2af00 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x0000000000d4bb40
certificate:
  subject: /C=PL/O=Asseco Data Systems S.A./OU=Certification Authority Division/L=Gdynia/ST=pomorskie/street=Podolska 21/postalCode=81-321/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=PL/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.1=Gda\\xC5\\x84sk/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=pomorskie/serialNumber=0000421310/businessCategory=Private Organization/CN=certum.pl
  issuer:  /C=PL/O=Unizeto Technologies S.A./OU=Certum Certification Authority/CN=Certum Extended Validation CA SHA2
ERROR: cannot verify certum.pl's certificate, issued by `/C=PL/O=Unizeto Technologies S.A./OU=Certum Certification Authority/CN=Certum Extended Validation CA SHA2':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to certum.pl insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Closed 3/SSL 0x0000000000d4bb40
```

The same happens when I specify CA certificates in the command - for wget: `--ca-certificate=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` and for curl: `--cacert /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

The ca-certificates version is now `2018.2.22-65.1.el6` - the newest. The openssl version is now `1.0.1e-57.el6` - the newest.

Do you have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Wget 1.12 is a very old version of Wget and it was probably compiled against a very old version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Probably you're right. But everything was ok, until I updated `ca-certificates` on 2018-07-12. Only after this update I got problems. So I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution for this problem with Centos 6 is to add the "missing" CA certificate to trust store managed by `ca-certificates`. I don't know why they removed it in that update. So:

1. Copy the root CA certificate from page "https://certum.pl/" to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
2. Execute: `update-ca-trust enable`
3. Execute: `update-ca-trust extract`

Still I don't know fully why `wget` wasn't working and `curl` was. When I tried `rpm -ql nss`, there was no information about any other trust store. I don't know where it can be located.

Answer (score 10):

`wget` is linked to OpenSSL whereas curl is linked to the NSS cryptographic libraries, which likely explains why they use different trust stores.

I don't have a RHEL 6 system nearby but probably `rpm -ql nss` will show a different/additional trust store compared to what OpenSSL uses.

This Red Hat resource may be of relevance https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003

In short: `update-ca-trust extract`

Comment: I tried this, but there is no change: still curl is working and wget is not. Interesting that `svn` has the same problem.